# IE7 Form Submit Doesn't Work

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer-7

Hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction - I have a form and for some bizzare reason it doesn't submit if the browser is IE7. IE8, 9, Chrome and Firefox all work without any issues so all I can think of is that it is using unsupported Javascript code. I think it's the line of code listed below.

```
$("#form_3next").click(function(){
$("#form_3action").val('next');
});
$("#form_3back").click(function(){
$("#form_3action").val('back');
});
$("#form_3finished").click(function(){
$("#form_3action").val('finished');
});
```

Here's a working example - http://www.bristolstreet.co.uk/contact-us/ any help would be greatly appreciated...

Best Wishes
Rachel

Comment: can you post the markup for your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through your page and I could not find "form_3next" or "form_3back". Maybe that's a problem (IE can break from the stupidest problems)...

Comment: Hi - the same issue is present on this page which does have the next and back button... any other thoughts? http://www.bristolstreet.co.uk/aftersales/car-servicing/book-a-service/

Comment: I'm looking into this now, it's a little complicated as it's a CMS which creates the forms so always a long winded way of creating something....

Comment: It's hard to tell.. I don't have a clue.. Does it show up any error?

Comment: Thanks it was that I had to dynamically add the functions relating to the buttons if and when they are present on the page